# GraphQL simple "hello" query returns NULL

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I have a list of queries/mutations/subscriptions that I wrote little bit ago and now I can't remember how GraphQL works.

All I'm trying to do is return a String that says "Hello".

### typedef

```
type Hello {
  message: String
}

type Query {
  hello: Hello
}
```

### resolver

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: () => 'Hello, world!'
  }
}
```

When I go to make a query in the GraphiQL visualizer with

```
{
  hello {
    message
  }
}
```

I get back

```
{
  "data": {
    "hello": {
      "message": null
    }
  }
}
```

Just in case it makes a difference I am using `apollo-server-express`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for an object named hello with a nested key named message.

What the query is actually returning is `'Hello, world!'.message` which is why it isn't erroring and returning null.

You either want to `hello: () => ({ message: 'Hello, world!' })` or just make the field type a string.

Comment: So im guessing if i wanted to also return other data, say a jwt for example, i would add it to the Hello type and in the resolver i would return `{message: 'hello', jwt: 'supersecretjwt'}`? Would this also work if i was trying to return a User as well as a jwt? So `{id: user.id, username: user.username, jwt: 'jwt'}`?